# How do I get JSFormat to preserve whitespaces that pad the inside of my functions and the like?

Tags: sublimetext2

When I run JSFormat, it turns:

```
function( stuff ) {
```

into

```
 function(stuff) {
```

How do I prevent this behavior?

Comment: As Terry said, the plugin uses JsBeautifier which does not have an option for this. If this is a big deal for you, head over to the github page for JsFormat here github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat and submit a feature request/enhancement. I've been looking for an excuse to dive in to the JsBeautifier source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no option for that.  JSFormat uses the [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) lib which trims all whitespace not associated with language syntax.

If you know Python you can edit [the source](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat) of jsbeautifier.py to exclude function trimming.

If you want to be really rough you could write a regex that just parses the file after it's done and modify your functions.  Something like

```
\(\w+\) \{
```

which would find

function **(stuff) {**

Comment: Thanks for answering!. I guess I need to subscribe to the sublimetext2 tag on here if questions about my plugins are starting to show up.

Answer (score 0):

The **jslint_happy** option solves your problem.